# same name with capital letters registration

Tags: php, pdo

Hello i have form register and edit with databse
my problem is when a name in the base is like this : jhon

another person he want to edit name url the same name but capital letters like : JHON - Jhon - joHN .... i want to refuse 
that's my code when I check

```
$url = addslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['url'])));

$stmtre = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT url FROM users WHERE url=:url LIMIT 1");
$stmtre->bindValue(':url',$url);
$stmtre->execute();
$rowre = $stmtre->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($rowre['url']==$url) {
    echo "refuse";
}else{
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET url = :url WHERE id=:id";
$UPD = $DB_con->prepare($sql);                                    
$UPD->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$UPD->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$UPD->execute(); 

echo"Done"; 

}
```

Comment: either use `LIKE` or 'cast' to lower/uppercase first ([and in sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)).

Comment: same problem i used like and upper and lower @Jeff

Comment: of course you need to do the same when you compare here `if($rowre['url']==$url)`

Comment: and what's the solution for check you have an idea please ?? @Jeff

Comment: You use strtolower for the comparison only, so something like: $user_data = $_POST['whatever']; $check_user_data - strtolower($user_data); This leaves $user_data in its original state for later filtering and use, do the same on the selected date from the database.

Comment: I can't see what a name and url have anything to do with each other and is unclear as to which param is linked for that. Is "john" related to the id here?

Comment: `addslashes(strip_tags` no idea why you're using those.

Answer (score 0):

use the SQL *LOWER* statement to compare the strings like:

```
 $DB_con->prepare("SELECT url FROM users WHERE LOWER(url)=LOWER(:url) LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: same problem i used like and upper and lower i can edit url with capital letters like  JHON - Jhon - joHN ....

Comment: Maybe prepare the post before (with strtolower) you use them 
$url = addslashes(strip_tags(trim(strtolower ($_POST['url']))));

Comment: but all capital letters change to tiny i want to save name like user write with capital or tiny you understand me brother @episch

Comment: okay, you can add a extra attribute, to write the a compare data. sha1($url) or like that, only for the selection on that url ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert everything to lowercase. In php and in sql:

```
$url = addslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['url'])));
// convert right from the start
$url = strtolower($url);
                                                       // here
$stmtre = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT url FROM users WHERE LOWER(url)=:url LIMIT 1");
$stmtre->bindValue(':url',$url);
$stmtre->execute();
$rowre = $stmtre->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// also here! ($url already is lowercase)
if(strtolower($rowre['url'])==$url) {
    echo "refuse";
} else {         
   $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET url = :url WHERE id=:id";
   $UPD = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
                    // now you already save the lowercase to db. 
                    // Not sure if that's what you want. 
                    // But it would make sense.
   $UPD->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
   $UPD->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
   $UPD->execute(); 

   echo "Done"; 
}
```

*EDIT*:

If you strip it down to the basics:

```
$url = "John";
$url = strtolower($url);
$compare = "joHn";
if(strtolower($compare)==$url) {
    echo "refuse";
}
```

you'll get 'refuse'. So either you're not showing full code or not implementing everything.
If you really whant 'John' and 'Jhon' to be 'equal': then it's getting difficult.

Comment: same problem brother there is in the base Jhon
after edit another user to JoHn he's accept

Comment: but all capital letters change to tiny i want to save name like user write with capital or tiny you understand me brother

Comment: you know, that `jHon` and `joHn` are not the same - even in lowercase? (and I'm not your brother btw)

Comment: after save in database he save like this : john not John

Comment: you don't need to be angry. we're just trying to help. If you dont want it, ok.

Comment: Yes, read my comment in the code. You now got all the tools you need - with @episch and my answers.